# Drawing/Drag Drop Vectors on an Image using SwiftUI

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, frontend

I want the user to be able to draw vectors that has a centered text in them on an image, in a way that the text stays centered in the vector while the user „drags and drops“ the vector

https://imgur.com/4ri5zek

Also I want the user to be able to change/write the centered text.
The video shows exactly what I’m trying to achieve, is there any way to achieve it using SwiftUI or are there any libraries that achieves something similar?